# Search form to add "sku" to url

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have a search form that refreshes the page when the submit button is hit with the table of results below. this works fine and the url is `http://example.com/?txtKeyword=searchterm` I want it to add `&sku=123456789` to the end of the url I know to add the sku from my database I need to use this term `$_GET[sku]`. I have tried to add this to the form and I have been unsuccessful. Here is the form code:

```
<form name="frmSearch" method="get" action="<?=$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']?>">
  <table width="100%">
    <tr>
      <th>Search: (Keyword/SKU)
        <input name="txtKeyword" type="text" id="txtKeyword" value="<?=$_GET["txtKeyword"];?>" size="40">
        <input class="alert button" type="submit" value="Search"></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

I think I need to add this line:

```
<form name="frmSearch" method="get" action="<?=$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']'&sku='$_GET["sku"]?>">
```

This does not work. I am not too sure, trying to learn PHP and I cannot seem to find the problem or a solution. Am I doing this wrong and what would I need to do to get this right?

Comment: You don't want to add another form, you'd want to add another `<input>`

Comment: Depends if your script is looking for a $_POST['sku'] or $_GET['sku'] when you process it. If its a POST then you add a new hidden input, adding it to action will  only work if it looks for $_GET['sku']

Comment: Thanks this worked, not sure why id didn't think of this. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Anigel: you should probably post that as an answer.

Comment: @AmalMurali I kind of posted it more as a question rather than an answer, but have reworded it slightly and posted it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Depends if your script is looking for a `$_POST['sku']` or `$_GET['sku']` when you process it.

If it is a POST then you add a new hidden `<input>`

```
<input type="hidden" name="sku" value="XXXXX">
```

adding it to the form action will only work if it looks for `$_GET['sku']`

EDIT

If you wish to echo something if its there but not if it isn't then do something like this.

```
<?php echo !empty($_GET['sku']) ? '<input type="hidden" name="sku" value="'.$_GET['sku'].'">' : ""; ?>
```

Comment: Run in to an issue with your solution i have add the following line:         <input name="sku" type="hidden" id="sku" value="<?=$_GET["sku"]?>" size="40">
and when i go to the page and enter a searchterm it doesn't show, i need to say that if no sku is found echo nothing else use the %_get["sku"], how is this done as i have tried some methods and it doesn't work